# Restore mailbox error in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010

I would like to restore one user mailbox into my account from recovery database. I have created recovery database -rdb and restore particular database in rdb.

I run get-mailboxstatistic -database rdb to check whether the mailboxes are their in restore-rdb database. It was showing all users mailbox.
I want to restore antony's mailbox from RDB database into jack's mailbox in the Restore folder.

When I run the following command:

```
C:\Windows\system32>RESTORE-MAILBOX -Identity jack -RecoveryDatabase RDB -RecoveryMailbox tony -TargetFolder restore
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
Mailbox "antony" doesn't exist on database "RDB".
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0:Int32) [Restore-Mailbox], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : F3FCE6D3,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.RestoreMailbox
```

While antony's mailbox is showing in rdb database.

Kindly advise.

Comment: Can you change the RecoveryMailbox name from the Alias to the Display Name and see if the command runs... Recovery is quite picky about what way you reference the account...

Comment: I tried other users name from rdb Database..but still getting same error.

Comment: Are you sure I'm almost positive that this error I've had before and this was why.. so if you go Get-MailboxStatistics -Database RDB then change both the identities in the recovery to the DisplayName with quotations " " you get the same error?

Comment: its working...i was missing one space in display name thanks dear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was happening due to Alias being used rather than DisplayName.

DisplayName was also inputted wrong on first attempt however spotted and corrected by user.

Please see comments for further details....

> Are you sure I'm almost positive that this error I've had before and this was why.. so if you go Get-MailboxStatistics -Database RDB then change both the identities in the recovery to the DisplayName with quotations " " you get the same error?